# jQuery POST does not submit form values using IE 11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have tried to find a solution for this problem for hours now, but the following code is simply not working for Internet Explorer 11. It does work for Chrome and Firefox. When using IE11 the post is submitted but the submitted form is empty.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="/Mandate/Edit" id="mandateForm" method="post">            
                <input id="ExternalId" name="ExternalId" type="hidden" value="" />
                <input id="mandateName" name="mandateName" type="text" />
                <a href="#" id="md-submit">Create</a>
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $("#md-submit").on("click", function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var form = $("#mandateForm");
                        var request = $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: form.attr("action"),
                            data: {
                                mandateName: "test4711"
                            },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            cache: false
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: can you replicate the issue in Jsfiddle.net.??

Comment: you have not mentioned the second inputs' type..??

Comment: try to use   data : JSON.stringify(form.serialize());

Comment: I have now added the input type to the second form field. Furthermore, I have removed the serialization and have just added a simple data field - still not working with IE.

Comment: How are you reading the form values on the server?

Comment: I am using ASP .NET MVC 4 and I try to read the value as shown below:

`[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MandateViewModel viewModel)
{
    viewModel.Name = Request.Form["mandateName"];
    return Json(resultModel, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}`

Comment: I am beginning to think that my IE may be corrupted or something, because I have tested this issue on other IE11 copies and it worked well on those.

Comment: Is this still opened? Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The `serialize()` method does not convert form data to Json...

This should work--the ouput in IE11 will be `{"ExternalId":"","mandateName":"4343"}`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="/Mandate/Edit" id="mandateForm" method="post">            
                <input id="ExternalId" name="ExternalId" type="hidden" value="" />
                <input id="mandateName" name="mandateName" type="text" />
                <a href="#" id="md-submit">Create</a>
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function form_to_json (selector) {
                  var ary = selector.serializeArray();
                  var obj = {};
                  for (var a = 0; a < ary.length; a++) obj[ary[a].name] = ary[a].value;
                  return JSON.stringify(obj);
                }

                $(function () {
                    $("#md-submit").on("click", function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var form = $("#mandateForm");
                        var request = $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: form.attr("action"),
                            data: form_to_json(form),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            cache: false
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The problem is that my IE seems not to be capable to handle any parameter whether its a stringified json object or a plain data value.

Comment: Use the IE developers tools (F12) to figure out what is diferent between your IE, and the other IEs. In the IE developer tools you can find a network trace option, that allows you to view the http requests made to the server.

Answer (score 0):

There eem to be some problems around with form serialization in ie in jquery. I usually use this plugin : http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api

This seems to be the easiest way to solve the problem. But its far from the cleanest way.  Another thing you could try is : make the server listen to json requestdata . and serialize it to a json string. Or make a serialize function yourself. which would be just like 3 lines of code.

Comment: I have removed the serialization now and replaced it with a data value - still not working.

Answer (score 0):

don't worry you try to send data with serialization() method i hope you problem may be solved
try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/Mandate/Edit" id="mandateForm" method="post">            
            <input id="ExternalId" name="ExternalId" type="hidden" value="" />
            <input id="mandateName" name="mandateName" />
            <a href="#" id="md-submit">Create</a>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#md-submit").on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var form = $("#mandateForm");
                    var request = $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: form.attr("action"),
                        data: $('form#myForm').serialize(),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache: false
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have changed the line data line to "data: $('form#mandateForm').serialize()" but it is still not working. As I have said before, also a simple data parameter is not submitted so I don't think the serialize function is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

i fetch the same problem but I solved this by adding this into head tag

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Today we encountered the same problem in IE11. I found out that this is working for me:

```html
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./index.php",
  data: { name: "John", time: "2pm" },     
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "./index.php",
      data: { name: "John", time: "2pm" },       
      cache: false
    });
}});
```

But this is not:

```html
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./index.php",
  data: { name: "John", time: "2pm" },     
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
}});

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./index.php",
  data: { name: "John", time: "2pm" },       
  cache: false
});
```

At this moment it looks like if you are executing multiple AJAX calls at the same time, the POST data will be empty, except the first call. When I am executing them after each other it works.

Answer (score -1):

I've found that activating "Enhanced Protected Mode" on IE11 solves this problem.

`Internet Options --> Advanced Options --> Enable Enhanced Protected Mode`

After that, restar the browser and the POST data is sent.